# Select distinct list of words if there are multiple words per record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please consider the following table:

```
words
-------------
foo
bar
bar, baz
foobar, foo, bar, dolor
lorem, ipsum
ipsum
```

I need a query to compile a distinct list of `words`, as follows:

```
foo
bar
baz
foobar
dolor
lorem
ipsum
```

How can I do this if I also need to split the `words` on comma?

Comment: There are 100's (probably 1,000's) of questions asking how to split a string in SQL Server on Stack Overflow, with a large portion marked as duplicates. What were wrong with those answers? What attempts have you made so far (post your code) and what were the problems you encountered?

Comment: I would ask why you have such a table in the first place. Your design violates 1NF by stuffing a bunch of values into a single tuple. If you had a properly normalized schema you wouldn't even have a question because the query would be so simple. Fix the design and your pain disappears.

Comment: Have you done some research???  Have you Googled your question???  There are tons of example on the web.

Comment: is your question how to get a list of `distinct` values _ordered by first occurrence_?

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server 2012 you can use on of the split functions available on the web (for example DelimitedSplit8K available [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)) to isolate single words. With `cross apply` you can apply the function to all the rows in your source table:

```
declare @words table (list_of_words varchar(8000))
insert into @words values
('foo')
,('bar')
,('bar, baz')
,('foobar, foo, bar, dolor')
,('lorem, ipsum')
,('ipsum')

select distinct(ltrim((rtrim(Item)))) as single_words 
from @words
cross apply [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](list_of_words,',')
```

Results:

[image]

Starting from SQL Server 2016 you can use `string_split` to isolate single words:

```
declare @words table (list_of_words varchar(max))
insert into @words values
('foo')
,('bar')
,('bar, baz')
,('foobar, foo, bar, dolor')
,('lorem, ipsum')
,('ipsum')

select distinct(trim(value)) as single_words 
from @words
cross apply string_split(list_of_words,',')
```

Comment: DelimitedSplit8K is a function by Jeff Moden. You didn't provide a link for it but what is more disturbing is that it cannot receive varchar(max). If you modified his code to accept that the performance will be horrific. He clearly states this in his article. You can find Jeff's article [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

Comment: @SeanLange You are absolutely right: my bad. I edited the answer also adding the link to the article. Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @words TABLE (
    Info    VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT @words
VALUES
('foo'),
('bar'),
('bar, baz'),
('foobar, foo, bar, dolor'),
('lorem, ipsum'),
('ipsum')


SELECT DISTINCT word
FROM (
    SELECT CAST('<X>'+replace(w.Info,', ','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as x 
    FROM @words w
) T1
    CROSS APPLY ( 
        SELECT n.D.value('.','varchar(100)') as word
        FROM T1.x.nodes('X') as n(D)
    ) T2
```